# Can I set the font size of a button inside the <Button> tag directly?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this code:

```
<Button x:Name="correctButton" HeightRequest="60" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
   <Button.FontSize>
       <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" x:Key="WindowBackgroundTable">
           <On Platform="Android" Value="20" />
           <On Platform="iOS" Value="25" />
       </OnPlatform>  
   </Button.FontSize>
</Button>
```

Is there a way that platform specific sizes can be set without have the

```
<Button.FontSize>
```

Comment: I don't have the time for a complete answer but you should check this (https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/32814/style-fontsize-onplatform-in-xaml)
You can define platform specific style and apply that style to your button in your Xaml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you will always need some kind of extra code like this if you want to make a difference per platform.

Normally, you would set it like this: `<Button FontSize="25" x:Name="correctButton" HeightRequest="60" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" />`

But you cannot distinguish values for platforms. What you could do, like Anto mentioned, is create a style and set the values, per platform, there. You code will look a bit cleaner in the page itself, but the idea remains the same.

To do this, in your `App.xaml`, add your style:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" x:Key="WindowBackgroundTable">
            <On Platform="Android" Value="20" />
            <On Platform="iOS" Value="25" />
        </OnPlatform>

        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{DynamicResource WindowBackgroundTable}" />
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

And remove the `FontSize` from your `Button`.
Like this, it is implicit, *every* `Button` in your app will be styled.

If that is not what you want, add the `x:Key` property to the `Style` tag, like so: `<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">`.

And edit your button like this: `<Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" Text="Welcome to Xamarin Forms!" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />`

Answer (score 2):

Well if you are only desperate about not having nested tags you could go this route:

```
<Label FontSize="{resources:PlatformedDouble Android=50, iOS=20}"></Label>
```

By declaring a markup extension like this:

```
public class PlatformedDouble : IMarkupExtension<double>
{
    public double Android { get; set; }

    public double iOS { get; set; }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public double ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        switch (Device.RuntimePlatform)
        {
            case Device.Android:
                return Android;
            case Device.iOS:
                return iOS;
        }

        return 42;
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    object IMarkupExtension.ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return ProvideValue(serviceProvider);
    }
}
```